# pyspark how to join on key but also inlcudes other columns?

Tags: pyspark

I have two RDDs that I want to join

```
RDD1
((a, b, c, d, e), 5)
((a, b, c, d1, e), 12)
((a, b, c, d2, e), 29)

RDD2
((a, b, c, f, e), 100)
```

I want the end join result as follow:

```
((a, b, c, d, e), 5, 100)
((a, b, c, d1, e), 12, 100)
((a, b, c, d2, e), 29, 100)
```

so the  join key is 'a,b,c,e'. as long as the key matches, I want to ignore the 4th column
and left join the total 100 back to RDD1.

I know how to do it in sql but not sure how to do it in pyspark. Here is my progress but I am not able to get the result, since I am not sure how to join the key and also have the 4th column back in as above.

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize((a, b, c, d, e), 5),((a, b, c, d1, e), 12),((a, b, c, d2, e), 29))
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(((a, b, c, f, e), 100))

rdd1.coalesce(50).map(lambda x: [x[0][0], x[0][1], x[0][2], x[0][4], x[1]]) \
.join(rdd2.map(lambda x: [x[0][0], x[0][1], x[0][2], x[0][4], x[1]])

(a, b, c, e, 5, 100)
(a, b, c, e, 12, 100)
(a, b, c, e, 29, 100)
```

any tips?

Comment: any reason you work with rdd rather than dataframe ?

Comment: could you add a working example of the input data, right now `a`, `b`, `c`, ... are not defined and your code crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your input a little (assuming a,b,c are strings), and added some brackets.

As for the solution, you can keep the whole of rdd1 in the first map, so that you can recreate your key after the join:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 5), (("a", "b", "c", "d1", "e"), 12), (("a", "b", "c", "d2", "e"), 29)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(("a", "b", "c", "f", "e"), 100)])

rdd_res = (rdd1.map(lambda x: ((x[0][0], x[0][1], x[0][2], x[0][4]), x))  # take the whole thing since we want to keep it
           .join(rdd2.map(lambda x: ((x[0][0], x[0][1], x[0][2], x[0][4]), x[1]))) # take just the last part to append
           .map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0], x[1][0][1], x[1][1])) # get rid of the temporary key and reformat so last two parts are flat
           )

rdd_res.collect()
#[(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), 5, 100), (('a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'e'), 12, 100), (('a', 'b', 'c', 'd2', 'e'), 29, 100)]
```